# Orden de finalizacion hilos java

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo un problema, necesito hacer 4 hilos que corran con números aleatorios, y cuando finalice el primero, tengo que mostrar la posición, es decir 1, y cuando acabe el último tengo que poner 4, pero no sé como saber cuando acaba el primero y el último

```
JLabel l1, labeltiempo, posicion;
int aleatorio;
double tiempo;

public void setE(JLabel l1, JLabel labeltiempo, JLabel posicion) {
    this.l1 = l1;
    this.labeltiempo = labeltiempo;
    this.posicion = posicion;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        aleatorio = Numeroaleatorio(1, 500);
        l1.setText("" + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(aleatorio);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Proceso1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
    long fin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    tiempo = (double) ((fin - inicio));
    labeltiempo.setText(String.valueOf(tiempo));
}

public static int Numeroaleatorio(int minimo, int maximo) {
    int num = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximo - minimo + 1) + (minimo));
    return num;

}
```

}

Este

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == iniciar) {
        a.setE(l1, t1, p1);
        a.start();
        b.setE(l2, t2, p2);
        b.start();
        c.setE(l3, t3, p3);
        c.start();
        d.setE(l4, t4, p4);
        d.start();

    }      

}
```

Comment: No hagas 2 veces la misma pregunta, edita la primera. -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274212/orden-de-finalizacion-de-hilos-java

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Orden de finalizacion de hilos Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274212/orden-de-finalizacion-de-hilos-java)

Comment: Meidante la función isAlive() puedes saber si un hilo determinado esta activo/ejecutandose. Aun así, no queda muy claro que es lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Hola, es facil lo que quiero hacer, tengo 4 hilos que empiezan a la vez, es como una "carrera de contadores" hasta 30, luego cuando el primer contador llegue a 30, tiene que aparecer el 1, de primer lugar, y asi sucesivamente. Lo estoy haciendo en un JFrame. pensé en poner un  while(hilo.isAlive) en la acccion del boton y dejarlo hasta que terminen los 4 hilos, pero en mi ventana los hilos no corren y solo aparece el resultado final.

Comment: Creo que una buena manera de hacerlo sería dejar que la clase que los instancia determine la posición, basándose en el valor de **labelTiempo**.